# req.user is undefined in express server

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, express, request

The code I am posting is in coffeescript.

```
http = require('http')
Url = require('url')
express = require('express')
bodyParser = require('body-parser')
paginate = require('express-paginate')
session = require('express-session')
passport = require('passport')
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
models = require(__dirname + '/database')


app = express()

app.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));
app.use bodyParser.json()
app.use bodyParser.urlencoded(extended: true)
app.use session(
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
  proxy: true
  resave: true
  saveUninitialized: true)
app.use passport.initialize()
app.use passport.session()

passport.serializeUser (user, done) ->
  done null, user.id

passport.deserializeUser (id, done) ->
  models.User.findById id, (err, user) ->
    done err, user

app.use (req, res, next) ->
  res.setHeader 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
  res.setHeader 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
  res.setHeader 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type'
  res.setHeader 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true
  next()
```

And my strategy :

```
passport.use new LocalStrategy (username, password, done) ->
  models.User.findOne { username: username }, (err, user) ->
    if err
      return done(err)
    if !user
      return done(null, false, message: 'Incorrect username.')
    if user.password != password
      return done(null, false, message: 'Incorrect password.')
    done null, user

app.post '/login', (req, res, next) ->
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) ->
    if err
      return next(err)
    req.logIn user, (err) ->
      if err
        return next(err)
      res.send "200"
  ) req, res, next

app.listen 9998
```

When i try to access req.user from another route, for example `/current_user` it is undefined.

```
app.get '/login/current_user', (req, res) ->
  console.log(req.user)  // this is undefined
  res.send req.user
```

I have read that `req.login()` should do the trick but it doesn't.

`req.user` and `req.session` exist only in the `/login` callback function.

Comment: You don't appear to show the code for the routes where you say `req` is undefined.  Since that is the code that is not working, please show that particular code.

Comment: Updated the question.